# Passing through -Verbose status to module cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a PowerShell module that encapsulates a number of commonly-used business functions. It's not generally called from the console; rather, its functions are called by automated deployment and management scripts that import the module.

The module incorporates a logging function that writes to both a centralised logging location. I'd also like to hook into the [Write-Verbose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) functionality to write to the console as well.

```
#'Start Script.ps1
#'----------------

Import-Module Corporate
Write-Logger 'Foo'
```

My restriction is that - from within the Corporate PowerShell module - I need to determine whether Script.ps1 has been called with the `-Verbose` parameter. Ideally, I would like the determination code entirely within the module itself.

Here's an example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ()

New-Module -Name TempModule -ScriptBlock {
    function Test-ModuleVerbose() {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param ()

        PROCESS {
            $vb = ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Verbose'] -eq $true)
            Write-Host ("1: Module verbose preference: " + ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Verbose'] -eq $true))
            Write-Host ("2: Module verbose preference: " + $Script:VerbosePreference)
            Write-Host ("3: Module verbose preference: " + $VerbosePreference)
        }
    }
} | Out-Null

function Test-Verbose() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ()

    PROCESS {
        Write-Host ("Verbose preference: $VerbosePreference")
        Test-ModuleVerbose
    }
}

Test-Verbose
```

Save the above as **test.ps1**. When invoked from the console:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1
Verbose preference: SilentlyContinue
1: Module verbose preference: False
2: Module verbose preference:
3: Module verbose preference: SilentlyContinue

PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
Verbose preference: Continue
1: Module verbose preference: False
2: Module verbose preference:
3: Module verbose preference: SilentlyContinue
```

As you can see, the $VerbosePreference variable is not available from within the module. Is there a way of picking up from within the module whether the calling script has been invoked with the `-Verbose` flag?

Comment: You can declare switch parameter for the script and then depending on it's value, set some global variable. Also you can set/unset environment variable and check it's value in the cmdlet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a variable named $VerbosePreference you can check to see how Verbose output should be handled. However, scripts loaded into a separate scope is giving you the issues. If you read the `Get-Help about_scopes`, you'll see:

> Script: 
>     The scope that is created while a script file runs.
>     Only the commands in the script run in the script
>     scope. To the commands in a script, the
>     script scope is the local scope.

You can add the script to the current scope instead using dot source notation. From the same help file, below the heading *Using Dot Source Notation with Scope* it is stated that:

> Scripts and functions follow all the rules of scope. You create them in a
>   particular scope, and they affect only that scope unless you use a cmdlet
>   parameter or a scope modifier to change that scope.
>
> But, you can add a script or function to the current scope by using dot
>   source notation. Then, when a script runs in the current scope, any
>   functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are available
>   in the current scope.

I suggest reading up more about scopes in the `Get-Help about_scopes` help chapter.

For a quick test of whether this works or not:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
PARAM()

New-Module -Name TempModule -ScriptBlock {
    function Show-ModuleVerbosePreference
    {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        PARAM()

        Write-Host "Verbose preference in module function: $VerbosePreference"
    }
} | Out-Null

function Show-ScriptVerbosePreference
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM()

    Write-Host "Verbose preference in script function: $VerbosePreference"
}

Show-ScriptVerbosePreference
Show-ModuleVerbosePreference</pre>
```

And if we try to call this script file using different methods we get the following output:

```
PS C:\> .\verbosity.ps1
Verbose preference in script function: SilentlyContinue
Verbose preference in module function: SilentlyContinue

PS C:\> .\verbosity.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Show-ModuleVerbosePreference'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Show-ModuleVerbosePreference'.
Verbose preference in script function: Continue
Verbose preference in module function: SilentlyContinue

PS C:\> . .\verbosity.ps1
Verbose preference in script function: SilentlyContinue
Verbose preference in module function: SilentlyContinue

PS C:\> . .\verbosity.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Show-ModuleVerbosePreference'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Show-ModuleVerbosePreference'.
Verbose preference in script function: Continue
Verbose preference in module function: Continue
```

So by using dot source notation we have added the script scope into the current scope which seems to make the VerbosePreference setting visible in the module method as well.

Comment: Thanks @robert.westerlund. I don't think I explained myself properly.

I know how to check whether the Verbose flag is set within a script. What I need is to be able to check - from within a PowerShell module - to see whether a script was invoked with the Verbose flag. I've updated my question to explain it better.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood you. What I think you'll need to look into is PowerShell scopes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @robert.westerlund. I think that dot-sourcing the scripts probably the closest I'm going to get.
Does seem bizarre though - given that a module is designed to be re-usable bit of code called from numerous places, you'd have thought it would be possible to pick up script-scope variables.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest reading up on scopes (Get-Help about_scopes) and you can why/how it works. :) I had to do the same, so perhaps you'll find a better solution than suggested above (and if so, please edit my answer).

Comment: @Dan I believe my answer is addressing your question of how to pass the `-Verbose` and other common parameters all the way through.

Comment: Trying "`Get-Help about_scopes`", I got an error. But this was PowerShell's fault and running *[`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Update-Help?view=powershell-5.0)* (as an administrator) fixed it. (Windows 10)

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to pass-through most of the common parameters using the matching preference variables and a syntax like this, `-Parameter:$ParameterPreference`. So, for the specific case of verbose, the syntax is `-Verbose:$VerbosePreference`.

There are a couple of exceptions:

- **Debug** : the value of `$DebugPreference` is automatically passed-through, *but specifying the* `-Debug` *switch forces* `$DebugPreference` *to* `Inquire`.
- **WhatIf** : automatically passed-through.

I have modified the OP code sample as follows:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param(
    [Switch]$FullPassThru
)

New-Module -Name TempModule -ScriptBlock {
        function Test-ModuleVerbose
        {
            [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
            param ()

            Write-Host "1: Module: verbose parameter is bound : $($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Verbose'])"
            Write-Host "2: Module: verbose preference         : $VerbosePreference"

            # Write-Verbose will just work without any change
            Write-Verbose "Verbose"

            # Other commands need the $VerbosePreference passed in
            Set-Item -Path Env:\DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU `
                     -Value 'You can safely delete this variable' `
                     -Verbose:$VerbosePreference
        }

        function Test-ModulePreferencePassThru
        {
            [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
            param()

            Write-Debug   "DebugPreference: $DebugPreference"
            Write-Warning "WarningPreference: $WarningPreference"
            Write-Error   "ErrorActionPreference: $ErrorActionPreference"

            Set-Item -Path Env:\DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU `
                     -Value 'You can safely delete this variable' `
                     -Verbose:$VerbosePreference `
                     -WarningAction:$WarningPreference `
                     -ErrorAction:$ErrorActionPreference
        }
    } | Out-Null

function Test-Verbose
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param()

    Write-Host ("Verbose preference: $VerbosePreference")
    Test-ModuleVerbose -Verbose:$VerbosePreference
}

function Test-PreferencePassThru
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param()

    Test-ModulePreferencePassThru -Verbose:$VerbosePreference
}

try
{
    if ($FullPassThru -eq $false)
    {
        # just demonstrate -verbose pass-through
        Test-Verbose
    }
    else
    {
        # most of the preferences can be explicitly passed-through, however:
        #
        #  -Debug  : $DebugPreference is automatically passed-through
        #            and -Debug forces $DebugPreference to 'Inquire'
        #  -WhatIf : automatically passed-through
        Test-ModulePreferencePassThru -Verbose:$VerbosePreference `
                                        -WarningAction:$WarningPreference `
                                        -ErrorAction:$ErrorActionPreference | Out-Null
    }
}
finally
{
    # cleanup
    Remove-Item -Path Env:\DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Save the above as **test.ps1**. When invoked from the console:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1
Verbose preference: SilentlyContinue
1: Module: verbose parameter is bound : False
2: Module: verbose preference         : SilentlyContinue

PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-ModulePreferencePassThru'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-ModulePreferencePassThru'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
Verbose preference: Continue
1: Module: verbose parameter is bound : True
2: Module: verbose preference         : Continue
VERBOSE: Verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Item" on target "Item: DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU Value: You can safely delete this variable".
```

Furthermore, pass-through for `$DebugPreference`, `$WarningPreference` and `$ErrorActionPreference` also works:

```
PS C:\temp> $VerbosePreference  = 'Continue'
PS C:\temp> $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
PS C:\temp> $WarningPreference = 'Continue'
PS C:\temp> $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -FullPassThru
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-ModulePreferencePassThru'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-ModulePreferencePassThru'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-ModuleVerbose'.
DEBUG: DebugPreference: Continue
WARNING: WarningPreference: Continue
Test-ModulePreferencePassThru : ErrorActionPreference: Continue
At C:\OAASMain\Online\ContainerService\Tools\docker\test.ps1:72 char:9
+         Test-ModulePreferencePassThru -Verbose:$VerbosePreference `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Test-ModulePreferencePassThru

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set Item" on target "Item: DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU Value: You can safely delete this variable".
```

`-WhatIf` is automatically passed-through:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -FullPassThru -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove Item" on target "Item: DEMONSTRATE_PASS_THRU".
```

This also handles `-WarningAction` and `-ErrorAction`:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -FullPassThru -WarningAction Ignore -ErrorAction Stop
Test-ModulePreferencePassThru : ErrorActionPreference : Stop
At C:\OAASMain\Online\ContainerService\Tools\docker\test.ps1:72 char:9
+         Test-ModulePreferencePassThru -Verbose:$VerbosePreference `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Test-ModulePreferencePassThru
```

Comment: `-Verbose`is a switch, not a string/set parameter, so setting `-Verbose:$VerbosePreference` will result in an error `Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'Verbose'` (at least in PowerShell 7).

The correct syntax to pass through Verbose is `-Verbose:($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')`

Answer (score 2):

In my .psm1, I place a command similar to this:

```
If ((Get-PSCallStack)[1].Arguments -like '\*Verbose=True\*') {
    Write-Host 'The .ps1 script importing this module is Verbose'
};
```

You may use the script block to set a variable, such as $VerbosePreference in your module scope, or your own unique variable for your own logic.

Answer (score -1):

Try the ContainsKey method:

```
$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey('verbose')
```

Comment: When executed from within the module, the BoundParameters collection always appears empty.